# Using "namespace foo {" instead of explicitly qualifying outside of header files

Tags: c++

If a function is declared as such:

```
namespace foo {
    void bar();
}
```

Most people define the function like this:

```
void foo::bar() {
    ...
}
```

However I like to do it this way:

```
namespace foo {
    void bar() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I prefer this style because its saves me from always retyping foo::, which is often tedious in function parameters that accept types declared in that same namespace. Plus its easier to rename the whole namespace.

I'm wondering why I almost never see my style in other peoples code, are there any disadvantages too it, besides the additional indentation level (and you don't even have to indent namespaces)?

Comment: `Most people...` really? `I'm wondering why I almost never see my style in other peoples code`, really?

Comment: eh? how big is this group of people who's code you've looked at? I rarely see the former...

Comment: I consistently use the same style that you do, with indentation... This seems a fairly subjective question to me.

Comment: You haven't seen all the good code I have written.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `foo::bar` form, and accidentally define the function with
incorrect arguments, you will get a compiler error.  If you put the
definition in a namespace in the source file, different arguments will
simply result in a different function being defined.  You won't get an
error until you try to link with code which uses your function (which in
the case of a DLL, may not be until runtime).

Comment: tl;dr: The `foo::bar` form can only be a definition, not declaration. I guess.

Comment: @Tomalak Yep.  The syntax isn't legal for declarations which aren't definitions.

Comment: "cannot be a non-defining declaration"* then :)

Answer (score 0):

Finding `foo::bar` on the command-line is not easy. Having `foo::bar` to grep for is quite nice.

Answer (score -2):

```
namespace foo {
    void bar {
        ...
     }
 }
```

Can cause multiple definition error. This error comes at link time.

Say that you have put this `namespace foo` in a header file and defined the function `bar()` inside it. Now, when you include this header file to multiple `.cpp` file, multiple definitions of `foo::bar()` will be generated. Thus, linker error.

[Note: I assume that in the 1st case, you are defining `foo::bar` in a .cpp file.]

Comment: Um, really? And the alternative "can" not?

Comment: @Tomalak, I din't get you. `namespace foo {
    void bar();
}` will not cause any linker error. Because I assume that `foo::bar()` will be defined in `.cpp` file.

Comment: Why 2 downvotes. What is wrong in the answer.

Comment: And you can assume that the same will be true of `namespace foo { void bar { .. } }`. The "issue" you're talking about has absolutely nothing to do with any difference between the two syntaxes.

Comment: @Tomalak, OP has asked `I almost never see my style in other peoples code, are there any disadvantages to it`. Forget it.

Comment: Again, what you are talking about is not a disadvantage of that style. It is a disadvantage of defining functions in headers, which you can do just as easily with either syntax.